# Why 不便 instead of 不便利?

Tags: grammar, words

Is there a grammatical (or semantic) reason that explains why the opposite of 便利（な） is 不便（な）rather than 不便利（な）。 I'm asking because I noticed a similar thing possibly occurring with 満足 and 不満 and was wondering if there was some underlying information that could help me better understand Japanese grammar.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Many on-yomi kanji compounds were made by combining two kanji with *similar* meanings.

- 満足: 満 ≒ 足 ≒ suffice; satisfy
- 便利: 便 ≒ 利 ≒ convenience; advantage
- 明瞭: 明 ≒ 瞭 ≒ clear; visible

This is because the on-reading of each kanji is [very short](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/24376/5010) and people needed two kanji to disambiguate. For example, マン by itself is too ambiguous because it can mean *ten thousand* (万), *chronic* (慢), etc.

But if you add 不, two kanji is often long enough and you may no longer have to say two similar kanji. There is no such word as <sup>[*]</sup>不万 (non-ten-thousand?), <sup>[*]</sup>不慢 (non-chronic?), <sup>[*]</sup>不勉 (non-study?) or <sup>[*]</sup>不弁 (non-valve?).

- 不満
- 不便

For some compounds, you cannot omit kanji at all (eg 不連続, 不確実). Or omitting one kanji may change the meaning a bit (eg 不明 = unknown vs. 不明瞭 = obscure). Basically you'll have to memorize each word individually.

Comment: Thanks for the answer as always. One follow-up. I understand that affixes are very much a case-by-case subject and applying rules to them might be a losing battle and I'm not trying to look for shortcuts but I wonder, are 不便利 and 不満足 categorically wrong? They're obviously not in common use (if at all) but if you heard them, would your native ears understand?

Comment: @G-Cam 不満足 is less common but [actually in use](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E4%B8%8D%E6%BA%80%E8%B6%B3-620261). 不満 also means *complaint* rather than *dissatisfied*. 不便利 is not used but at least we can understand :-)