# What are the differences between 賠 and 償?

Tags: meaning, usage, kanji

I am learning kanji with Heisig's method, and I have seen that **賠** and **償** means the same (compensation, indemnify), so I have been searching for examples in 'Yomiwa' and 'jisho.org' trying to clear my doubts. However, I couldn't find any answer of how difference those kanjis and how or when to use them. Thanks!!

I didn't have time to talk before, so okey. The trick is that I have usually watched them together, but in certain cases the aren't.For example:

**賠償金**, which means: indemnities; or **賠償** that means compensation (both words seems to means the same, okey)
Then, as 'agijonazo' said, **賠** is used in abbreviations so okey, i didn't spot that, thanks.

The other case is when **償** is alone as **償還** (amortization) or here: **償却** (repayment, but also can means amortization)

How do I know when to use them both together or just one alone?
Also, the translations seems to be similar (when one or both kanjis are in a sentence), are there sinonymous or just have a little different in japanese context?
e.g: 償却, 償還, 償い, 賠償, 賠償金 have equals meaning.

Sorry if I am not clear enough and thank so much all you

PD: I have read naruto's post but don't understand how that is apply here

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/83495/5010

Comment: You would have to learn how to use each **word**. Your question would make much more sense if it asked about differences between particular words that use those characters, rather than differences between individual characters.

Comment: Probably a practical answer is that 賠 is rarely used alone. 賠 and 償 both has *Kun*-reading つぐなう, but 賠 is unlikely to be used. You might be able to think 賠 means compensate *by money* because the left side (*Hen*) of 賠 (＝貝） usually means something about money.  Compare https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/kanji/%E8%B3%A0/  and https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/kanji/%E5%84%9F/.

Answer (score 3):

As a standalone word, 償 is used to write a Japanese word つぐなう (償う) that means "pay for (a crime or damage)". 賠 could also be read つぐなう, but virtually unused outside reading Classical Chinese books ([kanbun kundoku](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kanbun)).

As a part of Sino-Japanese compounds, 賠【ばい】 and 償【しょう】 have different connotations. 賠 means "pay money for damage or harm", while 償 is "give something (beneficial) in return to something done (good or bad)". It would be useful to know when you end up with coining a new word, which would be extremely rare though.

Answer (score 2):

I'll attempt to answer the question, but your confusion over the meaning is due to a general misconception you seem to have about how Kanji work.

You may have noticed that 償 has a *Kun* and an *On* reading, whereas 賠 only has an *On* reading. 償 can be part of a word, for example 償還【しょうかん】 where you would use the On reading. It can also be used by itself as the verb 償【つぐな】う = to make up.
In contrast, 賠 is never used by itself and must always be used with another Kanji.
Kanji that don't appear by themselves are hard to define in a dictionary and they typically take on the meaning of the words they're most commonly associated with. Since 賠 is most commonly written in the word 賠償【ばいしょう】= compensation, 賠 is defined as also meaning compensation.

Your question about when to use which of the two is missing the point: Knowing the meaning of Kanji doesn't tell you anything about how to use them and which words you can write with them. Also, knowing all the pronounciations of a Kanji doesn't tell you how to pronounce it in a given word. You'll simply have to learn the meaning of japanese words, memorize how they are written and also memorize how they are read.