# Statistics of on-yomi phonemes/syllables

Tags: readings, statistics

On-yomi of kanji feel a bit like they all sound alike. For instance, vowels /o/ and /u/ are over-represented.
Are there statistics of phoneme counts or syllable counts for on-yomi compared to kun-yomi? Something like: the top-100 syllables make up 20% of syllables for kun but 40% for on.

Comment: I used to have a link to a very simple website that had a series of tables with every possible on-yomi and which characters could be read with that sound... I'll try to find it, but you're definitely right in saying that the on-yomi all sound alike. They adhere to a certain pattern and there are only a limited number of possibilities (considerably less than the total phonological possibilities of the language).

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/24376/1478

Comment: According to [data from Funbit](http://funbit.info/kanji/readings/on_table_by_freq.html) (linked to from the thread mentioned by snailboat san): ショウand コウ are found in around 75 Jōyō kanji, シ in 52. ソウ, トウ and カン are between 42 and 45.