# What's the difference between 重責 and 責任?

Tags: word-choice, usage

What's the difference between 重{じゅう}責{せき} and 責{せき}任{にん}? They both have almost identical meanings - "Heavy responsibility" and "Responsibility". I found at [goo](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/104005/meaning/m0u/) even this example:

> 重大な責任。「重責を果たす」

Comment: You might have already answered your question... There is an emphasis on the weight of the responsibility in 重責.

Comment: But for me it is not very clear what is the purpose of 任 in 責任.. Why can't I say "重責任" - this is just for example.

Comment: The character 任 by itself means duty or obligation. 重 is heavy, 責 is taken from 責任 which is responsibility.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

責任 is *responsibility*, 重責 is *huge responsibility*.

This happens because many Sino-Japanese compounds are [made by combining two similar (or closely-related) kanji to reduce the number of homophones](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/15111/5010). The kanji 責 on its own has the meaning of *responsibility*, but it's too short and people usually use 責任 in sentences (責 is occasionally used as a standalone word, though). In words with more complex meanings, 責 is enough.

Similar examples:

- 病気【びょうき】 (disease) vs 重病【じゅうびょう】 (severe disease)
- 結婚【けっこん】 (marriage) vs 重婚【じゅうこん】 (bigamy/polygamy)
- 岩石【がんせき】 (rock) vs 巨岩【きょがん】 (huge rock)
- 帝王【ていおう】 (emperor) vs 女帝【じょてい】 (empress)
- 幸福【こうふく】 (happiness) vs 不幸【ふこう】 (unhappiness/misfortune)