# What is the difference between 約 and 約束?

Tags: word-choice

What is the purpose of adding 束 to 約 if the meaning stays the same and the other meanings of  約 are enough different to not be mixed up with the one in question?

> やく【約】の意味
>
> ［名］
>
> **１ 約束。取り決め。「約を交わす」「約を守る」**
>
> ２ 短く簡単にすること。また、そのもの。「長大な文章の約」
>
> ３ 「約音」に同じ。([source](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/221304/meaning/m0u/%E7%B4%84/))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The noun 約 is virtually not used in modern Japanese. If I understand correctly, it's not used even in official legal documents and such. Maybe an ancient character in a fantasy novel or a samurai drama might use this?

Anyway, 約 is too short, and people usually need a longer word for everyday usage. There are many kanji whose on-yomi is やく (訳, 役, 薬, 厄, ...). Please see the discussion below.

- [If 校 is the kanji for school, why do I need 学 to actually say school?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/15111/5010)
- [What's the difference between 重責 and 責任?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/53781/5010)